# What is the CSS API?

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

Noob Question:  Is the intention of the cSS API to make it possible to use the components as normal HTML without the need for any additional React code? Does the usage of only  the CSS API therefore require the inclusion of the React JS package or can the Blueprint JS package alone work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an author of Blueprint, I can confirm that it is **in fact possible to use *some* of the Blueprint components via CSS only.** Components that describe a CSS API in the documentation can be used without React, but usually with caveats (the biggest being that you must write the markup correctly). The CSS API is presented as an alternative to the JavaScript (React) API, and CSS modifiers are supported by the JS APIs through the `className` prop.

As Blueprint is a React-based UI toolkit, **the best experience will be had by using React**, primarily because you no longer have to write the markup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible to use the components as normal HTML, without ReactJS**. Blueprint is a **ReactJS UI toolkit** for the web.

Their pre-made (React) [components](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components) are customizable via a JavaScript API or a CSS API (or both).

The idea behind the CSS API, that some of the components have, is to provide additional options for style customization.

Let's use an example. See the [Menu component](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.menu). Its [CSS API](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.menu.css) allows us to modify Menu's style. One example is that we can add icons to menu items, read in their docs:

> Add icons to menu items the same way you would to buttons: simply add the appropriate `pt-icon-<name>` class*.

PS: I'd recommend you to head over the ReactJS docs, understand how ReactJS components work, get deeper knowledge about the core ReactJS concepts (or complete a fundamentals course) and only then - try to implement BlueprintJS.